# Custom file name from frontend in Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I'm uploading a file using FormData and receiving it server-side using Multer. Everything works as expected, except since I'm using FileSystem API on the front-end (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry), the files I'm uploading come from sub-directories. Multer seems to only see the filename, even if I explicitly set an alias for the file as I append it to form data (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append). It also seems like Multer performs its logic prior to the rest of my request handler and does not see the parameters I set on the body. How do I get multer to see the full path?

Here is a simplified version of what I currently have setup:

**Client** (alias represents full name with path, file.name is the base name automatically set by FileSystem API):

```
function upload(file, alias) {
    let url = window.location.origin + '/upload';
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let formData = new FormData();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                resolve(file.name);
            }
            else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
                reject(file.name);
            }
        })

        formData.append('file', file, alias || file.name); // this should in theory replace filename, but doesn't
        formData.append('alias', alias || file.name); // an extra field that I can't see in multer function at all
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
}
```

**Server**:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        // neither req nor file seems to contain any hint of the alias here
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
const upload = multer({storage: storage});
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) {
    // by this time the file seems to already be on disk with whatever name multer picked
    if (req.file) {
        res.status(200).end();
    } else {
        res.status(500).end();
    }
});
```

Comment: What does `req.body` show on the server show?

Comment: Within the function assigned to filename field in multer, it's empty, within the post request it contains the set alias, but by the time the post request handler starts, the file is already written to disk with original name.

Comment: Is `file.fieldname` set with the alias by any chance? (inside the `filename: function(){...}` what does `console.log(file.fieldname)` show?

Comment: `file.fieldName` is just set to `file`, unfortunately, the way I set it on the frontend (first argument to append). If I (as a hack) set it to the name I want, I'm not sure how I'd reference it from my upload.single call.

Comment: The file comes from form with multipart/form-data set on it, and multer already processes the files correctly, just doesn't see the alias I want to rename it to, I can even confirm the content is correct and the files are accessible.

Comment: @RichS are you referring to the callback inside `app.post` or the one passed to mutler's `filename`? Here is an example of what it looks like for one of the files in `app.post`:

`{ fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'base.css',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/css',
  destination: 'uploads/',
  filename: 'base.css',
  path: 'uploads/base.css',
  size: 1818 }`

Comment: And what was the alias you were hoping to set? Something other than "base.css", right? I was asking about `req.file` inside of `filename: function(){}` callback. It seems like that should definitely have your alias

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192819/discussion-between-richs-and-alexander-tsepkov).

Comment: No, the alias is supposed to be a full path, with the directory, base.css is the the basename that `event.dataTransfer` sets automatically. I can join you in chat in about 40 mins, need to grab a train home right now. I did fix this issue for now by renaming the file within the post handler manually via `fs` after mutler does its thing, but I would prefer a cleaner approach, if possible.

Comment: Have you tried setting `preservePath`? In multer cfg: `const upload = multer({storage: storage, preservePath: true});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get this to work, use the `preservePath` option when configuring `multer`. The following *will* work:

```
const upload = multer({storage: storage, preservePath: true});
```

However, it's important to note, `multer` will *not* create the directories or subdirectories. Those have to be created beforehand. (I tested this too. If directories are created and empty, upload succeeds, however, if directories do not exist, uploads fail).

In their [readme](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/), they say:
"Note: You are responsible for creating the directory when providing destination as a function. When passing a string, multer will make sure that the directory is created for you."

A follow-up to that note would be: "you are responsible for creating any sub-directories too".

The relative paths of files uploaded will be accessible in `originalname` property. So, backend would look like this: (as you had it, but with updated comments)

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        // If you uploaded for example, the directory: myDir/myFile.txt,
        // file.originalname *would* be set to that (myDir/myFile.txt)
        // and myFile.txt would get saved to uploads/myDir
        // *provided that* uploads/myDir already exists.
        // (if it doesn't upload will fail)
        // /* if(  [ uploads/myDir doesn't exist ] ) { mkdir } */
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
```

Helpful tip:
On the front end, I found it easier to test directory / subdirectory upload with: (tested on Chrome latest ok)

```
<form action="/uploads/multipleFiles" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="multiple" webkitdirectory accept="text/*" onchange="console.log(this.files)" />
      <input type="text" name="tester" value="uploadTester" />
      <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload Passport image as a front and back side then pass parameter from frontend like this **user:"username"** and **type:"front"** OR **type:"back"**
then Use it in node side like this

```
const upload = multer({
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'uploads/passport/');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, req.body.user+"-"+req.body.type+".jpg");
        }
    })
});
```